# Best protocol to communicate with backend (for iPhone apps)

Tags: iphone

We have a project to develop a backend system for items management. User can list item, search, view....etc

We need to develop an iphone app. for this backend, currently we are in the design phase of the API(s) and we are wondering which protocol best to use. The most important API is Search; this API must support paging, i.e. user can see 10 items and he/she can navigate throughout mutilate pages to see more results, just like Google. For each item a photo should be displayed plus a short description when the user clicks on specific item, he/she will get more details in tabbed form i.e. tab for description, tab for photos (which can be up to 30 photos)...etc

Performance and response time is very important for us, this will be insured in the backend but what about the iPhone app., what is the best protocol i.e. XML/HTTP, SOAP with attachment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The one that does the job with the less amount of effort. Usually REST and JSON. I don't know why would you use SOAP unless you are forced to plug with a web service environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, JSON rocks. It can even be used without too much change from a web page as well (this means you can have an HTML AJAX client and an iPhone App use the same API to communicate with your server).